# Instant moment Search in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to implement auto suggestion search on collection of data, looking for category related records where need to show the results as you type in Google.

I searched for gems and plugins but I didn't find any suitable required solution.

Could you please any one suggest me with any gems or other scenario approaches?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Implement of auto suggestion search on collection of data.

`jqueryui` is a great resource.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is a demo of `autocomplete`, you can view the source to see how to implement on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Use rails  https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem.
Its very easy to implement.